# Variable is used before being assigned, but why?

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code has the compiler complain about that the variable 'test' is used before being assigned. Clearly I'm calling and the function myFunc and it should be assigned right? If you uncomment assigning test at the same level it works, what's the difference between calling a function and assigning it directly?

```js
let test: number


function myFunc() {
    test = 200
}

myFunc()

// uncomment this and it works
// test = 200

test.toFixed()
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=15&pln=3&pc=1#code/LAKFBsFMBcAJsgZ2gLlgOwK4FsBGkAnUYkAM03QGNoBLAe3VmwE8AxCygCgEpYBvULCHwkcALywATAAZpoAL4kW7KjxIB6dbA51s2SOjjQAFjUSwAhugAmsGnADudAgGtEoTSOSwJMuWBAEZAA6aDpWGgAPSGseIA

Comment: I don't believe Typescript interrogates functions to see if they make an assignment or not. There is nothing in the code that guarantees that the assignment happens before the function is invoked on it. It is a type system, but it doesn't execute the code. It would work if `myFunc` returned 200 and the result of that invocation was assigned to test or if test was given an initial value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve simply changing declaration row in:
let test: number = 0;

If you dont't do this, compiler can't know what you will do in myFunc();